# Unable to upload images in ios 11.0.3

Tags: ios, swift3, uiimage, alamofire, uiimagepickercontroller

I am facing a really weird problem. I am trying to pick an image and upload the same after cropping it, to the server. I am unable to do it on my iphone 5s running on ios 11.0.3. But the same is working fine on iphone 5 which is running ios 10.3.3.

I am using the following code to pick the image from gallery:

```
    func showImgPicker()
    {
        self.imagePicker.allowsEditing = false
        self.imagePicker.sourceType = .photoLibrary
        self.present(self.imagePicker, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }

    @IBAction func getImgs(_ sender: UIButton) {



        let photos = PHPhotoLibrary.authorizationStatus()
        if photos == .notDetermined {
            PHPhotoLibrary.requestAuthorization({status in
                if status == .authorized{
                    self.showImgPicker()
                   } else {

                }
            })
        }
        else
        {
            showImgPicker()
        }

    }

   @objc func imagePickerController(_ picker: UIImagePickerController, didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo info: [String : Any]) {

    let imageURL = info[UIImagePickerControllerReferenceURL] as! NSURL

        picker.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
        dismiss(animated: true) {
            self.delegate?.presentEditor(img: (info[UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage] as? UIImage)!, id: self.id!, type: self.commentType)
        }

    }
```

And once the image is picked, I am sending it for copping, post that the image is being saved in the local document directory of the app:

```
 static func SaveImgLocal(img: UIImage, tsStr: String) -> String
{
    let fileManager = FileManager.default
     do {
        let documentDirectory = try fileManager.url(for: .documentDirectory, in: .userDomainMask, appropriateFor:nil, create:false)
        let fileURL = documentDirectory.appendingPathComponent("\(tsStr).jpeg")

        if let imageData = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(img, 1) {
            try imageData.write(to: fileURL)
            return "\(tsStr).jpeg"
        }
        else
        {
            return Constants.MESSAGE_ERROR
        }
} catch {
    return Constants.MESSAGE_ERROR + " " + error.localizedDescription
}
}
```

And finally I am uploading the image to the server:

```
let url2 = URL(string: "file:///private\((url?.absoluteString)!)")

            print(url2)
            print(url)


            let salesObj = try SalesFactory.getSalesService()

            try uploadDoc(url: Urls.uploadImgUrl, docUrl: url2!, parseResponse: { (result) in
                print(result)
           }


 public static func uploadDoc(url: String, docurl: URL, httpResponse: @escaping (DataResponse<Any>) -> Void) throws
{


    let hdr: HTTPHeaders = ["Accept": "application/json"]




    Alamofire.upload(docurl, to: url, method: .post, headers: hdr).responseJSON { (response) in
        print(response)
        httpResponse(response)
    }

}
```

The same code works on ios 10.3.3 but not on ios 11.0.3. There are no errors. The server sends a message mentioning upload failed.

Comment: Is there any error messages printed?

Comment: No, no errors printed.

Answer (score 0):

Added NSPhotoLibraryAddUsageDescription in info.plist and compressed the image. Its started working.

Anyone facing this problem, please add both NSPhotoLibraryUsageDescription and NSPhotoLibraryAddUsageDescription in info.plist.